# How to show the Persian numbers in applescript?

Tags: applescript, arabic, persian

Actually I've a simple code that it shows the page number in English , is there anyway to show them out in Persian or Arabic numbers ?

my applescript is :

```
    tell application "myApp"
    if (count documents) > 0 then
        set pageCount to count (pages of document 1)
        repeat with pageNumber from 1 to pageCount
            set thePage to page pageNumber of document 1
            make new text imprint at end of imprints of thePage with properties {rich text:pageNumber as rich text, x position:36, y position:36, height:16, width:30}
        end repeat
        return pageCount
    end if
end tell
```

the output is like this :

```
1,2,3,4,5
```

and I want to be like this :

```
۱,۲,۳,۴,۵
```

Comment: You need to specify the numbering system of the used locale to `arab`.

Comment: @Eng.Fouad, it won't work ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set the page number as string, so you can write a routine that shows a persian number in string format of an `integer` value

```
    tell application "myApp"
    if (count documents) > 0 then
        set pageCount to count (pages of document 1)
        repeat with pageNumber from 1 to pageCount
            set thePage to page pageNumber of document 1
            make new text imprint at end of imprints of thePage with properties {rich text:my intToPersianString(pageNumber), x position:36, y position:36, height:16, width:30}
        end repeat
        return pageCount
    end if
end tell


on intToPersianString(intValue)
    set persianSymbols to "۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹"
    set output to {}
    repeat with i in characters of (intValue as string)
        set end of output to character ((i as integer) + 1) of persianSymbols
    end repeat
    return output as string
end intToPersianString
```